# TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function

Tags: typescript, typeerror, strapi

my Function:

```
export const getStrapiUrl = (path): string => {
  if (path == null) {
    return "";
  }
  console.log(path);
  return `${
    path.startsWith("/", 1) ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL : ""
  }${path}`;
};
```

Error message from console:

{ url: '/uploads/work_with_74e76d4826.png' }

```
error - utils\get-strapi-url.ts (7:9) @ getStrapiUrl
TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function
   5 |   console.log(path);
   6 |   return `${
>  7 |     path.startsWith("/", 1) ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL : ""
     |         ^
   8 |   }${path}`;
   9 | };
  10 |
```

Comment: 1. What is `path`? 2. If it is a string, are you using [an environment that supports `startsWith`](https://caniuse.com/?search=startswith)? It's most likely that `path` isn't a string, though.

Comment: I would assume that `{ url: '/uploads/work_with_74e76d4826.png' }` in your question is what's logged? If so then you probably want `path.url.startsWith ...`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the output `{ url: '/uploads/work_with_74e76d4826.png' }`, `path` isn't a string, it's an object. You could, however, extract the `url` part of it:

```js
return `${
  path.url.startsWith("/", 1) ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL : ""
}${path.url}`;
```